# How large can a NPC village be?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to embark on a massive Minecraft build that includes NPC villagers. Now I would like to know how large of a "village" I can make. I was reading that they have to be within 16 blocks horizontally from a door to register. Also, I read that to transplant villagers to another village they have to be moved at least 32 blocks away from their original village.

Does this all mean that I can only make a village that is up to 64 blocks across?

Also, since wells are considered to be the center of a village, can I create wells every 64 blocks to create another village adjacent to one?

Comment: try and keep each question to one question c:

Comment: Sorry about that. I was just trying to figure out how large a village can be and if I can bypass that size limiter with additional wells. Most importantly, I would like to know how large a village can be.

Comment: From what I understand, you also want to simulate a larger village by having two (or more) villages situated next to each other, is this right?

Comment: Basically yes. I would like to build a large city/town and have lots of villagers there to trade with. It's going to be part of a server spawn town. I just haven't read or seen anything that helps me to answer this, that's why i'm asking.

Comment: No need for apologies, just giving advice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Essentially, infinite.

The value of 32 blocks determines how far away from an existing village a villager must be to create a new village. Hence, if you build a load of [village structures](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_NPC_Villages) 32 blocks apart, you will have saturated the land with villages. Then, just expand from your 'nodes' to create a village around each one. From the villagers' perspective, there will be a separate village every 32 blocks, but from the players' they'll all appear to be the same.

So by 'Essentially infinite' I meant you can create a continuous village-scape that will be populated with villagers, and each actual village therein will be ~64x64.

Comment: Thank you! Alright, what do you mean by "Village structures" or nodes, is that a house or well or...? Thanks again

Comment: It's a house. Wells do not define a village; you can have a village without a well.